# SQL Server 2019. Need to update particular column in particular row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like this:

```
LinN | RecType | Value
-----+---------+--------
1    | 01      | 12345
2    | 02      | Null
3    | 03      | Null
4    | 05      | Null
6    | 01      | 67890
7    | 02      | Null
8    | 09      | Null
```

I need to make it look like this:

```
LinN | RecType | Value
-----+---------+--------
1    | 01      | 12345
2    | 02      | 12345
3    | 03      | 12345
4    | 05      | 12345
6    | 01      | 67890
7    | 02      | 67890
8    | 09      | 67890
```

I tried a cursor, `Lead` and `Lag` - but nothing is working for me.

Any idea/help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Be great to see what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cumulative max:

```
select LinN, RecType, Value,
       max(value) over (order by try_convert(int, LinN)) as imputed_value
from t;
```

You can incorporate this into an update:

```
with toupdate as (
      select LinN, RecType, Value, max(value) over (order by LinN) as imputed_value
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set value = imputed_value;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it as soon as I come back to office.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work Statement select LinN, RecType, Value, max(value) over (order by LinN) as imputed_value
from t; returns data like this

Comment: @lion  . . . "does not work" is not a helpful comment.  You should explain what the problem is.  An error?  Can you set up a fiddle to show the issue?

Comment: Comments editor not allowed to show the problem. Stement select LinN, RecType, Value, max(value) over (order by LinN) as imputed_value from t; retrieves wrong data. Iputed_value is always equal value 12345 - Value in very first row. I need to brake it every times when Record Type is 01.

Comment: My fault. I forgot to tell that value in column named ‘Value’ is not a number. It is varchar which looks like like number. It icomes from legacy system and I cannot control it.

Comment: @lion . . . Just convert it to a number.

Comment: I cannot. Next time it could be ‘A12345’

Comment: @lion . . . That is not the question that you asked here.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question and provide appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your time.I prefer do not ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 0):

Moderators, please close this discussion. I do not see any reason to keep it active.
Thank you everybody for your time.